# ¿Cómo reflejar el índice original de los items de una lista, al crear una sublista de la lista original? --Python3

Tags: python

Con fines didácticos he intentado a partir de una lista, obtener el 'type' de cada item de la misma, y luego generar dos sublistas con los elementos 'Mutables' e 'Inmutables'.
Mi pregunta se refiere a ¿cómo puedo reflejar el índice original de los elementos que componen las dos sublistas?

```
L = [0b11, -17.5, 'kilo', [49, 'V', 'ram'], (5, 'echo'), 7, "0b11", -89.5+2.125j, tuple('spam'), {'food': 'spam', 'taste': 'yum'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}]

print("Dada la lista, hallar el tipo de cada item y crear dos listas (inmutable y mutable)",
      '\n')
print(L, '\n')

immutable = [float, int, complex, str, tuple]
mutable = [dict, list, set]

found = []
fou = []

for item in range(len(L)):
    for i in range(len(immutable)):
        if ((type(L[item])) == immutable[i]):
            if L[item] not in found:
                found.append(L[item])
    else:
        for item in range(len(L)):
            for i in range(len(mutable)):
                if ((type(L[item])) == mutable[i]):
                    if L[item] not in fou:
                        fou.append(L[item])
    
print("Immutables", found,'\n')

for item in range(len(L)):
    for i in range(len(found)):
        if item == i:
            print("index ", item, found[item], "es", (type(found[item])), "inmutable")

print('\n'"Mutables", fou, '\n')

for i in range(len(fou)):
    print("index ", i, fou[i], "es", (type(fou[i])), "mutable")
```

Obtengo la respuesta que refleja el tipo de cada item (mutable o inmutable), pero no he logrado presentar el índice original de cada item (es decir -17.5 = L[1], y así para cada item en cada sublista.

```
> Mutables [[49, 'V', 'ram'], {'food': 'spam', 'taste': 'yum'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}] 

index  0 [49, 'V', 'ram'] es <class 'list'> mutable                   # index_original 3
index  1 {'food': 'spam', 'taste': 'yum'} es <class 'dict'> mutable   # index_original 9
index  2 {'a', 'b', 'c'} es <class 'set'> mutable                     # index_original 10
```

Gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar y obtener el índice simultáneamente.
Para ver si un elemento está en una lista también puedes usar el operador in.
Puedes guardar el elemento y el índice en un tuple (item, index)

```
immutable_found = []
mutable_found = []
for (index, item) in enumerate(L):
    if type(item) in immutable:
        immutable_found.append((item, index))
    if type(item) in mutable:
        mutable_found.append((item,index))
```

Ahora puedes imprimir la información que quieres accediendo a los elementos del tuple

```
for item in mutable_found:
    print("index ", item[1], item[0], " es ", (type(item[0]), " mutable")
```

Comment: Gracias @JGR por la pronta respuesta, el código funciona para lo que quería. Un pequeño detalle en el print: `(type(item[0])` **)** , item --> item[0]
`print("index ", item[1], item[0], " es ", (type(item[0])), " mutable")`